# How to parameterise all strings in android application

Tags: android

I am building an application and I am thinking of how to "parametrise" all the strings in the application (is it even possible) in order to allow me to change them easily without "redeploying" it again ...

meaning it will be somewhere in a file with strings (something like you have PO files in PHP when using templates and different languages) where I can manage it ..

it might be useful when I would like to use different languages :)

I am kinda struggling on this one, so I was thinking if you can give me a clue or show me where to "go" to study how this should be implemented ..

Thanks

Comment: in the values folder inside your project resources, there's a strings.xml file(or you can create it) that centrally holds all your app's strings.

Comment: Do you expect said strings to change (i.e.: new strings) during the lifecycle of your application? Because Strings.xml (in all the flavors/variants) are compiled as Resources during the build of the project, you cannot modify them at runtime. If that's a requirement, you'll have to roll your own mechanism that has a `Map<Key, Value>` with your "strings"

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes, I would like to avoid rebuilding it - so I can change texts "on the fly" without redeploying it again and potentially forcing users to update ... can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think you've already gotten a couple of answers. If you don't use the built-in mechanism because you don't want to "redeploy" then you need to obtain your strings and keys from something (a Webservice/RestAPI/something). So you'd get a list of Key/Value like: "app_name": "YourApp", "login_title", "Login:", etc. You'd need one of those per language. Then you store these maps in a list or map, and then when you need a string: map.get("app_name")... (you obviously need to pull from the correct language). Not rocket science, but also a rare requirement (I've had to do this twice and it's a PITA)

Answer (score 1):

If you want different langage in your app, create as many strings.xml files as you need. However, when you add new strings file, you have to redeploy.

To avoid that, you should call a specific API in backend which send you all the texts according to the langage of the device. For that you must manage back and front.

Comment: so for all strings in app I have to call a BE microservice that will handle this? so I can eventually have those strings stored in a db ?

Comment: You will need to ship the strings with your app

Comment: If you use the BE, you can retrieve a file, a json... anything you want, save it locally and fill all texts with the content. But the easiest and best way remains creating different strings.xml, like explained in other answers

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correcly go to `res - >value folder -> strings.xml - >` open it and you will see something like this:

```
<string name="app_name">this is your app name</string>
```

And now every time that you want text to be "this is your app name" all you need to do is **to add this line:**

```
android:text="@string/app_name"
```

And when you will change the actual string in strings.xml it will also change in every place he is being used (`android:text="@string/app_name"`)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built-in mechanism for localising assets (Strings included)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#creating-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is known as '**Localisation**', this can be helpful if you want to give users different language support and similar kind of stuff.

In android, this is done by putting all the strings in the **Strings.xml** file located in the **res** folder.

If you're using android studio, just press **Alt + Enter** on any hardcoded string and then select **'Extract string resource'** from the popup, give the name of the string and Voila! you're done.

It is also a part of good coding practice, in fact you've might have noticed 'Lint warnings' in your layout files if you type any hardcoded string, and it asks you to add this string in the strings.xml file

You can create a separate String file for each language that you wanna include.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Using the Default Built-In Mechanism

You already have answers about this or you can [read the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor) about it. 
Essentially, you maintain an `xml` file called `strings.xml` which is a key-value of Strings. Each file (one per language) will be located in a `values` folder. E.g.: for french, you'd want `values-fr/strings.xml`. Each file will include all the translated strings. If a value is not found in French, then the english file will be searched instead as a fallback. If the key is not there, the app will crash (if I am not mistaken).

**Pros**

- Included with the system
- Supports many languages
- Packed at compile time, always available.

**Cons**

- Resources are "read-only" once they are compiled; you cannot change a string and save the change this way.

#### Option 2

Roll your own Thing.

If you need to be able to dynamically alter these strings, you'll need a few key pieces:

1. A way to obtain/download said strings.
2. A default in case step 1 fails (what if the user cannot download them?) You need defaults.
3. To ensure *every widget* that needs to display text, calls your own creation of a class that can manage said dynamic strings (i'll elaborate down below)
4. You need to know what to do if a String is somehow magically missing; because this is dynamic, there has to be a fallback in case the string is not found (see 2)
5. This has to be relatively fast (you don't want expensive lookups when constructing strings and UI elements).

**Pros**

- You can model this the way it works best for you
- You will be able to load strings as you see fit and even change them at runtime.

**Cons**

- You have to build all this.
- It's error prone, and most likely slower than the native solution.
- You must ensure you don't miss strings and that you have dafults.
- You must modify normal widgets (say TextView) to understand how to fetch the strings (or you must *always provide them*), and this is not going to be automatic, you'll either have to delegate or subclass into a `YourCustomTextViewThatUnderstandsYourStringThing extends TextView` (name... is just a *draft* ;) )
- You must ensure you don't leak memory by keeping strings in memory you don't care anymore.
- If you want to "persist" these downloaded languages (and you should), you have to write/use your own persisting mechanism (either by writing the files or by using some database, shared preferences is not the place for these).
- You need to cache them (see above) and manage the validity of the strings (what if they become old, can they become old? when should you re-fetch them?)
- etc.

As you can see it's not trivial and each app has its own world of problems to solve, but that's roughly what it means.

As for "code"... the simplest way I can think of (or rather, the bare basics) are:

1. Find a way to "store" the strings: e.g.:

`Map<String, String> oneLanguage`

So in this Map, you store the KEY (to find the value) and the VALUE:

`oneLanguage.put("app_name", "My Super App")`

2. Keep all the strings in one place in memory:
   `Map<String, Map<String, String>> allLanguages`

so then you do:

`allLanguages.put("English", oneLanguage);`

Now you can add other languages:

```
anotherLanguage.put("app_name", "Mi Super App"); //my Spanish is top-notch
allLanguages.put("Spanish", anotherLanguage);
```

Now you have a place where to store (in memory) all your keys/values for each language.

When you want to retrieve Spanish, you'd have a method like:

```
String getString(@NonNull String locale, @NonNull String key) {
   return allLanguages.get(locale).get(key);
}
```

And then you'd need to (either manually or via subclassing or whatever approach you find more convenient) to set these strings like:

```
// I mean, don't hardcode the locale... but you get the idea.
appNameTextView.setText(yourLanguageManager.getString("Spanish", "app_name"));
```

What approach you take for this last step, is entirely up to you.

As usual, all the above is pseudo-code, and *not a complete solution* to this approach. Things you want to do: ask the device what locale is using, keep track of which locale is in use (so you don't have to pass it every time), fetch these locales from your server (not pictured) :), persist these to disk, as well as save in shared preferences, the "locale" key that the user has selected, add methods to your `yourLanguageManager` so it can have things like:

- `boolean updateLocale(String locale, Map<String, String newStrings)`
- `boolean deleteLocale(String locale)`
- `Map<String, String> getLocale(String locale)`
- etc.. you get the idea.

All in all, it's just a simple data structure that can contain keys and values.

Good luck!